# What’s the most efficient way to find the coordinates of all internal edges of a 3D grid?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array, edges

I need to find the coordinates of all the internal edges of an image. I have tried to achieve this with the following procedure:

1. Generate grid using pixel size of 0.5
2. Obtain coordinates of all vertices.
3. Remove all unwanted rows:

   - Rows with all integer values
   - Rows with 2 non-integers
   - Rows with all non-integers
4. Re-sample your grid using mesh size of 1 pixel.
5. I feel that resampling the grids with a pixel spacing of `1` will leave me with the coordinates obtained in `step 3` as the coordinates of the edges.

The code is as follows:

```
% input image
Ydim = 3;
Xdim = 3;
Zdim = 3;


% generate 3D mesh using a pixel spacing of 0.5
[xgv, ygv, zgv] = meshgrid(1:0.5:Xdim - 1, 1:0.5:Ydim - 1, 1:0.5:Zdim - 1);

% obtain coordinates of all internal vertices and edges
allCoords = [ygv(:), xgv(:), zgv(:)];

% Obtain only the coordinates of edges by keeping only two integers and one
% non-integer in each row
edgeCoords = allCoords;
edgeCoords((sum(mod(allCoords,1)~=0, 2))~=1, :) = [];


% re-sample 3D grid using a pixel spacing of 1
[columnsInImage, rowsInImage, pagesInImage] = meshgrid(1:Xdim - 1, 1:Ydim - 1, 1:Zdim - 1);


% plot points 
plot3(edgeCoords(:,2), edgeCoords(:,1), edgeCoords(:,3), '.b', 'markersize', 20)
hold on;
grid on;

scatter3(edgeCoords(:,1), edgeCoords(:,2), edgeCoords(:,3));
```

I am not exactly sure of the assumption in 5) above, as well as the overall procedure. Hence, I need someone to help me look at this. Is my assumption correct? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Lastly, I would love to visualize this better than I already have in the code. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: What are your desired coordinates relative to? Window coordinates? Screen coordinates? I'm a bit confused on what you meant by internal edges. Does internal edge mean edges pointing toward the center of the mesh?

Comment: @Jon I am using image coordinates (i.e. screen coordinates?) system. I will explain the internal edges with an example: a 3x3x3 grid will have 8 internal vertices and 12 internal edges. I hope that makes sense? Thank you Jon.